# Ln integration problem?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me solve the following integration problem? Using u substituion.

$$\int\frac{\ln(x+a)}{x+a}dx$$

I have looked at this problem but I cannot seem to solve it if I use $u=(x+a)$ I would get $du=(1+a)\,dx$.

It does not seem correct.

Comment: $a$ is a constant, so with $u = x+a$, you get $du = dx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=\ln(x+a)$. Then $du=\frac{1}{x+a}\,dx$. We end up with $\int u\,du$.

**Remark:** If we make the substitution $u=x+a$, then we get $du=dx$ and we end up wanting $\int \frac{\ln u}{u}\,du$. That's fine. However, we are not finished, and need the further substitution $v=\ln u$.

When we made the substitution $u=\ln(x+a)$, we collapsed two substitution steps into one. But you might wish to do it in two steps.

Comment: That makes sense, the question hid the fact you posted.

Comment: Would my final answer be correct $\frac{\ln(x+a)^2}{2}$ ?

Comment: To make it clear that we are not squaring $x+a$, I would write $\frac{(\ln(x+a))^2}{2}+C$.

Comment: Or put the square right on the ln, that is, just right above the letter n before the "open" bracket